# Alto AGS 2019 (Pakistan) no Parking mode

Tags: alto

Usually auto car is having P-R-N-D all modes & in UAE i drove a lot of cars but i never saw any car with out P mode , i am planning to buy alto AGS 2019 in Pakistan but in online review i saw there was no P on car gear ~ its just R-N-D only. Whats with that ~ i even tried to contact with Suzuki but they didn't answered my call. I really need to know how can we put car in parking mode. i dont like idea to put car in N and pull hand break.

Comment: What is wrong with using the hand brake, manual transmission cars don't have a 'P' to select.

Comment: @HandyHowie I always wondered whether the P transmission lock was just cheaper than designing an "emergency brake" that was powerful enough to be useful ;)

Comment: @alephzero I have not noticed a difference in hand/emergency brakes between manual and auto versions of the same car, but my experience has been limited to UK cars.  Have you noticed some?

Comment: @HandyHowie parking on a steep hill can be an issue. That's when I leave a manual transmission in gear.

Comment: An auto 'box only has a small (about 5mm) parking pawl, so having seen some shear I always rely on the handbrake and angle the wheels to/from the kerb...... You makes your choice...

Answer (score 1):

According to this review [Suzuki tests Dzire’s new AGS gearbox](https://www.bworldonline.com/suzuki-tests-dzires-new-ags-gearbox/):

> There is no “P,” or park gear. “With the AGS, when you turn off the engine, the actuator would always shift down to first gear, which will act like the parking mode, Mr. Adia said.

Although the review is of a different model, it features Suzuki's AGS transmission system.